# Implementing Bootstrap theme in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

There are three issues I'm having with using a bootstrap purchased theme:

- Where do you put the CSS/img/font/js folders?
- What do you update to compile them?
- How do I get navigation to work across the site?

For reference I have bootstrap set up and running successfully mostly using: https://medium.com/@biancapower/how-to-add-bootstrap-4-to-a-rails-5-app-650118459a1e

I put the theme folder in the public folder, took from the pages > index.html the following and put it in the head on the application.html.erb:

```
<link href="css/loaders/loader-typing.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="preload" as="font" href="fonts/Inter-UI-upright.var.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preload" as="font" href="fonts/Inter-UI.var.woff2" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Then I moved from the theme folder the css and font folder to be directly under public. Boom no issue. Then I added all the @import 'bootstrap/mixins' etc. under application.scss. No issues. I updated my nav from the theme folder > pages > index.html. No issue. I added in a link...and I noticed issues that probably go back to the links in the header.

My nav does not carry over into another link. So for example I have in my users > index.html.erb:

```
<div class="container'>
 <%= @users.each do |user| %>
  <p>user.full_name</p>
 <%end%>
</div>
```

The navigation will appear at the top but the dropdowns do not work across the site. Did I miss something?

My application.js file has:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Application.scss has:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'users';
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/type";
@import "bootstrap/images";
@import "bootstrap/code";
@import "bootstrap/forms";
@import "bootstrap/buttons";
```

Gemfile has:

```
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
```

My nav partial has the following (abbreviated):

```
<div class="navbar-container>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" data-sticky="top">
  <div class="container">
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: If the dropdowns are not working it likely has to do with jquery not being loaded, can you verify that jquery is being loaded on the page?  Are you seeing any errors in the consloe like `$ is undefined`?

Comment: So there are tons of errors in the console but they're all about JS files for Bootstrap that I don't know where to put. There's nothing with $ is undefined on the home page and then nothing on the users page beyond the same JS errors. Bootstrap is still working on the users page as container still works.